# lambda expression and filter function to extract words from a list

Tags: python, list

I am writing a program that extracts all list elements starting from 'b' using lambda expression and filter function, but I am just getting empty []'.

In []:

```
x = ['bread','rice','butter','beans','pizza','lasagna','eggs']

criteria = lambda value:value==['b']  
     
c_list = list(filter(criteria,x))
c_list
```

Out[]:

```
 []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `lambda` together

```py
list(filter(lambda item: item.startswith('b'), x))
```

**EXPLANATION**:

`lambda` function will either return `True` or `False` based on whether string item startwsith `b` and filter will just call the same lambda function for each item in the list, and will keep only the records for which `lambda` returns `True` value, Finally, you need to type cast it to a list, since filter function gives a filter object which is an `iterable`.

**OUTPUT**:

```py
['bread', 'butter', 'beans']
```

You can just update your lambda expression to check the first character in the value parameter:
Either: `criteria = lambda value:value[0]==['b']` or: `criteria = lambda value:value.startswith('b')`

Answer (score 1):

Check the first value of the word using indexing.

```
x = ['bread','rice','butter','beans','pizza','lasagna','eggs']

criteria = lambda value:value[0]=='b'
     
c_list = list(filter(criteria,x))

print(c_list)
```

prints

```
['bread', 'butter', 'beans']
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try using a list comprehension here as well:

```py
inp = ['bread','rice','butter','beans','pizza','lasagna','eggs']
output = [x for x in inp if x.startswith('b')]
print(output)  # ['bread', 'butter', 'beans']
```